# NodeJS Removing Npm-Cli.js When I Try Installing For a Second Time (I installed through the zip then extracted)

Tags: node.js, npm

So basically I installed the zip file from the node.js download page and I extracted it then I used cd to go into the folder then installed discord.js and it worked perfectly fine until I tried installing fs. It came up with an error that there was no \node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js and idk what to do because it gets removed. Any help

I tried re-installing the zip file and doing what I did before but the same thing happened.